# Change the background color of an html tag from a dropdown menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, html-select

So i have this select tag

```
<select id="patient_color_id" name="patient[color_id]">
 <option selected="selected" value="1">blue</option>
 <option value="2">yellow</option>
 <option value="3">green</option>
 <option value="4">red</option>
</select>
```

The values 0...4 are coming from a db so i cannot change them to the hex color value.
Anyway in my jquery file i have

```
$("#patient_color_id").change(function(){
if($(this).val() == "1"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#00FFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "2"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#F0FFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "3"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#0FFFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "4"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#FFFFFF");
}
});
```

So when i am choosing a color from the dropdown menu the background color of the general-info div should change, but nothing happens and i can't figure out what is wrong.

ps. I am using rails but i don't believe that this has something to do with. All the other scripts that i use are working fine.

Comment: Did you wrap that in a document ready ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Cross-browser support for styling `<option>`s is very poor, and non-existent for some browsers.

Comment: Firstly, `element.value` always returns a string, so the quotes are correct. Secondly, where does it say `.general-info` is an option element ?

Comment: I tried with double/single/without quots, and opened it with chrome/firefox/nothing works. The .general-info is a the class of a div tag. The selector is cointained within this div-tag.

Comment: Might be a problem somewhere else in your code. What you posted above seems to work fine in a sandboxed environment, assuming the JS runs after the DOM elements in question have loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/2RXmx/

Comment: do console.info($(this).val()) and see what you get

Comment: hmmm.. It dows work in the sandbox.. but i dont gen anything on the control...

Comment: You know you can do [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/PXNLd/1/), right ?

Comment: Do you use the rendered id? (Just in case you are using asp.net or something that renders the ids for you)

Comment: This should NOT be tagged as ruby-on-rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the code looks correct, you might be the adding the listener before rendering the dom. To check if that is the case you can try and see if the below code works.

If this works try to add listener after the dom rendering is done.

```
$("#patient_color_id").on("change", function(){
if($(this).val() == "1"){
alert("1");
$(".general-info").css('background-color', "#00FFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "2"){
alert("2");
$(".general-info").css('background-color', "#F0FFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "3"){
alert("3");
$(".general-info").css('background-color', "#0FFFFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "4"){
alert("4");
$(".general-info").css('background-color', "#FFFFFF");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks! i added $(document).ready(function(){ mycode here }); and it works just fine!

Answer (score 3):

I copied your code into jsFiddle and added in the generalInfo div and your code seems to work fine. The only observation I'll make is that some of your color values display as white, perhaps invalid hex values for the color so that could be misleading you. You can check out the jsFiddle here if it helps. I'd recommend wrapping in 
but that shouldn't really matter since you are bound to a change event.

Here's the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danieljordan13/G7v9r/

Only thing I changed is the color values to random ones I know work.

```
$("#patient_color_id").change(function(){
if($(this).val() == "1"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#ddbbFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "2"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#aaddFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "3"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#cceeFF");
}
if($(this).val() == "4"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#bbbbFF");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Subtle Colors Too Subtle**

Actually, the jQuery is fine, the color codes were a bit too subtle perhaps to be seen on some monitors:

Try:

```
$("#patient_color_id").change(function(){
if($(this).val() == "1"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#0000FF");
}
if($(this).val() == "2"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#FFFF00");
}
if($(this).val() == "3"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#00FF00");
}
if($(this).val() == "4"){
    $(".general-info").css('background-color', "#FF0000");
}
    alert("color: "+$(this).val());
    alert($(".general-info").css('background-color'));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yazhk/

The alerts are for diagnostic purposes only.  A red herring, quite common.